# Jsf InputText not working properly with barcode scanner

Tags: jsf, primefaces, barcode-scanner

I'm facing an issue while scanning a barcode with an usb barcode scanner.
The scanner's functioning is simple: you scan a barcode and it write the read string as a text(tested on a .txt file)  but when I use on the follow code it returns me to the home page logging out from the website.

```
<h:outputText value="barcode*"  />
<p:inputText value="#{myBean.barcode}"
             maxlength="16>
     <p:ajax event="blur" 
             update="@this" 
             listener="#{myBean.checkBarcode()}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

I tried some debug and saw that the method checkBarcode is not called, so i suppose that the scanner do something authomatic, like printing a tab or new line or something else.
is there some attribute on the p:ajax or the inputText that can avoid this kind of issue?

Comment: Off topic: you might want to have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/codeScanner.jsf for a code scanner that integrates with JSF.

Comment: nope, it's not the same issue. In the question you linked it's something relate to the set of the value while my problem is that it's like the scanner set the value and press "enter" on the keyboard

Comment: Isn't the type of event you're using wrong? [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) is an event that notifies you when to lose focus. Barcode scanners in keystroke emulation mode usually notify you of the Enter key as a sign that you have finished notifying one barcode. You can register an event handler for the [KeyDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) event and call the process to check the barcode when the Enter key is notified. There are many such cases on the Web, so please look for them.